# How to add some content when viewing custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type

I'm developing a wordpress plugin and I got a custom post types with some meta datas. for example we got meta data "code" and "name".
the thing that I want is in viewing post page (example.com/?post_type=1) show the meta data first and then the content of that post.
is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit the template for your post type, this should be `single-yourposttype.php` if you don't have one create one - clone single.php if you need to.

Then within that page before the_content() use:

```
global $post;    
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'code', true );
```

Where "code" is the name of your meta field, repeat that second line for as many meta data fields you have and need.

Comment: as I said Im developing a plugin , so there should be no changes to template !!!
if I need to create that file , where shall I put it ?
should I call it somewhere in my plugin ?

Comment: You can have the template in your plugin folder - and use the following add_filter() function - see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template to tell the site to use your template for your custom post type